# Read JSON array from websocket data feed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, websocket, antd

ReactJS - TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
this.ws.onmessage = e => {
  var tbox = JSON.parse(e.data);
  this.setState({
  user : this.state.usernames.concat(tbox.data[0].user),
  messages : this.state.messages.concat(tbox.data[0].message)
})
console.log(tbox.data[0].user + ': ' + tbox.data[0].html);
```

I'm trying to parse, setState and display data in realtime (in a Ant Design List component) from a public websocket api.

I managed to get thus far but if someone can better help me steer in the right direction, that would be much appreciated!

```js
const URL = 'wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=chat:1'

const data = [
  {
    user: 'buythediplosers',
    message: 'im over here waiting for nothing lol',
    time: '4:20 AM', /*TODO: let the user set their timezone*/
  },
];


class Trollbox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        usernames: [],
        messages: [],
        timestamps: [],
    }
  }

  ws = new WebSocket(URL)

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log('connected')
    }

    this.ws.onmessage = e => {
      var tbox = JSON.parse(e.data);
      this.setState({
        user : this.state.usernames.concat(tbox.data[0].user),
        messages : this.state.messages.concat(tbox.data[0].message)
      })
      console.log(tbox.data[0].user + ': ' + tbox.data[0].html);
    }

    this.ws.onclose = () => {
      console.log('disconnected')
      this.setState({
        ws: new WebSocket(URL),
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <List
            itemLayout="horizontal"
            dataSource={data}
            renderItem={item => (
              <List.Item>
                <List.Item.Meta
                  description={
                    <div>
                      <p>
                        <b>{item.user}</b>: {item.message} {item.time}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  }
                />
              </List.Item>
            )}
          />
        </div>
...
```

```js
console.log(tbox.data[0].user + ': ' + tbox.data[0].html);
```

shows me what I want to see in the console, which is a step forward for me: 
[image: console output]

```js
   console.log(this.state.usernames + ': ' + this.state.messages);
```

though, this bunches it all up unlike the previous line while still giving me an error:

[image: error message]

EDIT: JSON sample:

```
{ 
   "table":"chat",
   "action":"insert",
   "keys":[ 
      "id"
   ],
   "data":[ 
      { 
         "channelID":1,
         "date":"2019-11-27T07:20:30.862Z",
         "fromBot":false,
         "html":"Keepitreal: ok bruh\n",
         "id":43087881,
         "message":"Keepitreal: ok bruh",
         "user":"cryxix"
      }
   ],
   "filterKey":"channelID"
}
```

Comment: Kindly post your json data sample.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I edited the question! https://i.imgur.com/U8BCBsn.png

Comment: try to console tbox variable and see if it is returning data or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this.ws.onmessage" handles every message from the other endpoint, so you have to make sure your code can handle every case that could happen.

first time json without tbox.data comes, tbox.data is undefined, so you have the error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

second time the error is "Cannot read property 'user' of undefined", so tbox.data is not undefined but tbox.data[0] is undefined. I think tbox.data is a empty array(data : []).

if you want to use tbox.data[0].user, check tbox.data[0]  is not undefined.

try

```
if(tbox.data && tbox.data.length > 0){ .....}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the images you provided in your comments, this one: 
[image: errors]
Shows that the first 3 responses you are getting are different than the ones you are expecting, and don't have key called user in it, hence why you are getting that error. You can skip over it by adding a conditional like:

```
if(tbox.data){
      this.setState({
        user : this.state.usernames.concat(tbox.data[0].user),
        messages : this.state.messages.concat(tbox.data[0].message)
      })
}
```

In regards to your second question,

> though, this bunches it all up unlike the previous line while still giving me an error:

This is because you are posting the entirety of your `this.state.usernames` which is repeatedly growing larger as an array. If you want to post it that way, you have to loop through the state and log each one separately.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, and tried to edit it before you saw it, it should read ```if(tbox.data)``` not ```tbox.user```